# TNS-Core-Modules dependency conflict with Nativescript 8

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I inherited some Nativescript code that was working fine for iOS but failing for Android.

My environment is:
android sdk 11
jdk 14
node 16

My package.json dependencies are:

```
"dependencies": {
"@nativescript/core": "~8.1.1",
"@nativescript/firebase": "^11.1.3",
"@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.1",
"nativescript-vue": "~2.9.0",
"tns-core-modules": "^6.5.27"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@nativescript/android": "8.1.1",
"@nativescript/ios": "8.1.0",
"@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.0",
"nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "~2.9.0",
"sass": "^1.32.8"
}
```

The issue seems to be arising from the implementation of push notifications where a requirement is grabbing the UUID of the device.

In the initial version of the code, they were using a library called "nativescript-uuid".  Using that library and targeting iOS seemed to work fine.  However, when targeting Android, I would get an error that it could not find something like " cant find module tns-core-modules/platform....".  I looked into tns-core-modules and saw it wasn't in my node_modules folder, and I added it as a dependency using tns plugin add "tns-core-modules".  That removed that specific error but introduced a new one about conflicting class names:

```
Warning: there already is an extend called com.tns.FragmentClass.
Warning: The static binding generator will generate extend from:vendor.js implementation
java.io.IOException: File already exists. This may lead to undesired behavior.
Please change the name of one of the extended classes.
File:C:<APP DIRECTORY>\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\tns\FragmentClass.java 
Class: com.tns.FragmentClass
at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBindings(Generator.java:112)
at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Main.main(Main.java:55)
```

Before I go down a rabbit hole of google searches, I was wondering if anybody had any idea why this would be failing in the first place and if there were any suggestions on how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That plugin hasn't been updated in some time.  There's a fork, [@kefah/nativescript-uuid/](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@kefah/nativescript-uuid/), that promotes itself as being NativeScript 8 compatible.